# Reuse of user keywords with multiple inputs

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to call same user keyword in different location using different inputs. How to do it?

```
*** Keywords ***
Enter the Server Name
    Wait until element is visible   ${ServerIPField}  ${Timeout}  "Input field not loaded"
    Log     "Input field loaded. Entering server name"
    Click element  ${ServerIPField}
    Input text  ${ServerIPField}   ${ServerDetails}
    Log   "Server name/IP ${ServerDetails} entered to the server name/ip field"
```

in the above code,
ServerDetails field will have different inputs based on the usage locations (say i call this keyword in TC1 and then in TC3). I want to give different inputs for each test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the variable `${ServerDetails}` as argument to the keyword.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test 1
    Enter the server name    ${server_1_details}

Test 2
    Enter the server name    ${server_2_details}

*** Keywords ***
Enter the Server Name

    [Arguments]    ${ServerDetails}

    Wait until element is visible   ${ServerIPField}  ${Timeout}  "Input field not loaded"
    Log     "Input field loaded. Entering server name"
    Click element  ${ServerIPField}
    Input text  ${ServerIPField}   ${ServerDetails}
    Log   "Server name/IP ${ServerDetails} entered to the server name/ip field"
```

For `Test 1` the keyword `Enter the server name` is called with the value stored in `${server_1_details}` and in `Test 2` is called with the value stored in `${server_2_details}`.

Comment: And here is a link to the corresponding RF docs: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#named-arguments-example :)